# What is a more efficient way to create counts of data ranges?

Tags: sql, postgresql

"Group data by ip then count the repeats. Over 1 visit, over 2 visits, over 5 visits, over 10 visits."

I ended up writing queries that look like this

```
select (select count(*) from (select ip_agent_md5, count(*) as cnt from $table group by ip_agent_md5 having count(*) > 1)) as over_1_visit \
, (select count(*) from (select ip_agent_md5, count(*) as cnt from $table group by ip_agent_md5 having count(*) > 2)) as over_2_visits \
, ... from my_table;
```

What is a more efficient way to write this if I still need it inlined in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT some_column, sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as over_1,
                    sum(case when cnt > 3 then 1 else 0 end) as over_3
FROM
(
    SELECT some_column, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY some_column
) x
```

Comment: Thank you stranger